# Setting up a picture thumbnail service on Amazon Ec2 - bare minimum PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am looking for a good strategy for setting up a thumbnailing service on the Amazon EC2  free tier +S3, with only the essentials.

After trying a few Lamp configurations on the Micro instance, 610~ MEGS, I am usually left with around 50-200 megs of memory for the actual image processing. There has to be a better way, with an even smaller footprint.

One idea would be to install Debian Squeeze + Php 5,  - would this be all I need? Just Shell commands? No apache, nginx, lighthttpd, etc?

I haven't tried the tutorial as featured in the docs here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1602

as it seems to be unnecessarily complicated and expensive with too many moving parts.

Any ideas, links to tuts or duplicate posts would be a great starting point.

Comment: have you tried installing imagemagick and use the command line, or just exec on php to do it?

Comment: @John I try will that--- Just imagemagick, php5, and the OS, right? I'm new to enviroments outside of LAMP and really appreciate your guidance!

Comment: Yes, that is how I usually do it. Imagemagick is easy to use and has a  very low footprint.

Comment: Yeah you might want to use nginx or lighttpd instead of apache. Another possiblity would be to use Node.js instead of php and then execute imagemagick or another conversion library from that (not sure if node has image manipulation available).

Comment: @John Excellent! I will try that and post my findings on here. I have a class that handles GD, however, and have been mulling over trying imagemagick. I give this a shot & post my findings on here if I can get it working correctly. ~~regards

Comment: @prodigitalson Question--- Do I even need nginx or lighttpd? Could I just do this with shell exec? Just wondering-- thanks!

Comment: Well you have to have something to process the http request right? I mean you could build your own socket server i guess... but i would think at some point youd need more http level features and at that point itd be better to jsut use a lightweight http server

Comment: @prodigitalson Gotcha! I was only asking because I was also brainstorming a scheduled routine, daemon, that would blindly do the resizing via shell. Just accessing the s3 bucket and following instructions via the aws message queue, no http requests whatsoever. However, been meaning to scratch this nginx itch for some time now:)

Comment: Oh well if youre goinh to use an MQ then yeah you probably could do it all from the shell assuming you got some other outside way to post a message to that queue (i assume over http).

Comment: i've been using small instances on the ec2 spot market for less than a cent an hr for weeks. just backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FORGET THIS!

After consulting with my buddy, Jaisen, who runs theopenphotoproject.org, he suggested using imagemagick for resizing a set of thumbnails before uploading.

*Before* uploading. Heh.

Why overcomplicate things? Sometimes the easiest way is still the best way.